# contactus form submit email dont send

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using a template website that is practically finished, but the form submit dont work.
Pls anyone can help me?

Here is my basic html:

```html
<form action="#" class="form-contact" id="contactForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="p_name" placeholder="* Nome" required="">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="p_email" placeholder="* Email" required="">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="p_phone" placeholder="* Telefone">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="p_subject" placeholder="* Assunto">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="p_message" class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="* Mensagem"></textarea>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div id="success"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ENVIAR</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

here is my form-process.php:

```
<?php

$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

// SUBJECT
if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Subject is required ";
} else {
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
}

// MESSAGE
if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
}


$EmailTo = "myemail@outlook.com";
$Subject = $subject;

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Something went wrong :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}

?>
```

Here is my ajax/javascript for sending the email:

```
$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Did you fill in the form properly?");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});


function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#p_name").val();
    var email = $("#p_email").val();
    var subject = $("#p_subject").val();
    var message = $("#p_message").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&subject=" + subject + "&message=" + message,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "Message Submitted!")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm").removeClass().addClass('shake animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada animated text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#success").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
```

I was never able to send a form, I always get the error "Did you fill in the form properly?"

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: @DipenShah you talk about this? 
 <!-- SENDMAIL -->
 <script src="js/vendor/validator.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/vendor/form-scripts.js"></script>

 <script src="js/script.js"></script>

Comment: Yes, most likely its issue with your validator script. Did you debug?

Comment: @DipenShah I don't know if that will be it, I had it all day and I can't find the solution. If you can help me I would be forever grateful. here is the complete link of my website to the script http://reidemoure.com/l/js/vendor/validator.min.js

Comment: Check my anwer.

Comment: @DipenShah friend i find the problem. Its my HOST omg dont read correct php file i think. i just try on other host and work perfect. Code its ok.

Comment: Please delete / close the question.

Comment: @DipenShah I try on free host and work perfect. no problem with code. my isp host said dont use PHP mail().. and advised me to change to framework SMTP, like PHPMailer() or SwiftMailer(). No ideia how to change this. can you help me?